# Algorithm for checking if a cubic graph has a triangle

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

If we have a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges, then in general, the problem of listing all triangles in $G$ is solvable in $O(m\sqrt{m})$ time [1]. If we consider only the planar graphs, then the same problem can be solved in $O(n)$ time [2]. I am interested in the similar problem for cubic graphs (3-regular graphs) or for graphs with maximum degree at most 3. For me, answer for the most basic question will suffice: is there an efficient algorithm for determining if given graph of maximum degree 3 contains a triangle?

EDIT: When I say "efficient algorithm" I mean running time $O(n\log^cn)$, for some constant $c \geq 1$.

[1] Alon, N., Yuster, R., Zwick, U. (1997), Finding and counting given length cycles, Algorithmica, 17(3), pp. 209–223.

[2] Papadimitriou, C., Yannakakis, M. (1981), The clique problem for planar graphs, Inform.
Proc. Letters 13, pp. 131–133.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any graph, we can also loop through all the vertices, and for every vertex $v$, check if any of $v$'s neighbors are adjacent to each other. This is at worst an $O(n \cdot \Delta(G)^2)$ algorithm, where $\Delta(G)$ is the maximum degree of $G$.

It's easier to explain, but not as good as the algorithm in the first paper you cite which runs in $O(n \cdot d(G))$, time, where $d(G)$ is the degeneracy of the graph: the smallest value of $k$ such that every subgraph has a vertex of degree at most $k$.

But in the case of cubic graphs, both $\Delta(G)$ and $d(G)$ are constant, and so even the simple algorithm runs in $O(n)$ time.

Comment: how about more general question: listing all triangles of cubic graphs? How many triangles can cubic graph have?

Comment: This algorithm should also be able to list all the triangles as it finds them.

Comment: (I guess to avoid listing a triangle multiple times, we check if $v$ is the lowest-indexed vertex in a triangle.)

Answer (score 3):

If the maximum degree of the graph $G = (V, E)$ is at most $3$, then the problem of listing all triangles in the graph can be solved in $O(n)$ time. The algorithm is quite simple.

> 1. for each edge $e = (u, v)$ in $G$:
> 2. $\ \ $let $\ell_u$ ($\ell_v$) be the adjacent list of $u$ ($v$) such that the vertices are ordered in the list;
> 3. $\ \ $find all $w \in \ell_u \cap \ell_v$ using $O(|\ell_u| + |\ell_v|)$ time and output the corresponding triangles;

The complexity of this algorithm is $O(\sum_{(u, v) \in E}(\delta(u) + \delta(v)) = O(|E|) = O(n)$ because $\delta(u), \delta(v) \leq 3$ and $|E| = O(n)$.

Comment: You answer is very good, but Misha Lavrov was 1 minute faster :)